# bootstrap classes isn't applied to navbar component in angular application

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

i'm using bootstrap 3.4.1 with angularcli 6.0.8, but when i run ng serve my web page shows none of the bootstrap classes i identified.

i've tried updating bootstrap versions and trying new class still not working.

[image]

```
<div>
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Dating App</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Matches</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Lists</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " href="#">Messages</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="text" placeholder="Username">
      <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="password" placeholder="Password">
      <button class="btn btn-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Login</button>
    </form>
  </nav>
</div>
```

in angular.json

```
"styles": [ "src/styles.css" ],
"scripts": []
```

in src/styles.css

```
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
```

Comment: Try to put the link that you have added to `style.css` at the angular.json file something like this.
`"styles": [ "src/styles.css" , "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"],` and tell me if this works or not

Comment: do you see the classes when you inspect the elements? I mean, your form looks like it has bootstrap styling.

Comment: @ZhuniqiA no it didn't work

Comment: @DanOswalt yes i can see the classes in the elements

Answer (score 0):

You are using plain CSS, so the `@import` statement is executed by the browser. I'm guessing that, if you open the Network tab of the Dev Tools, you'll see a nasty 404 regarding the bootstrap.min.css file.

The simplest way to import the css is including that in the `styles` array in `angular.json`:

```
"styles": [ "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css", "src/styles.css" ],
```

This will produce a `main.css` file embedding the Bootstrap css.

Answer (score 0):

Install Bootstrap for the project via npm: `npm i bootstrap`

Note that Bootstrap depends on both Popper.js and jQuery - both of which you also need to install via `npm i jquery popper.js`

Later try to add these in the **angular.json**

```
"styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
            ]
```

Comment: are the dependencies of jQuery , bootstrap and popper js are found under **node_modules** ? if yes make sure you have copied the same which i have defined for **styles** and **scripts** @youssefSULTAN

Comment: i've double checked the references and there is nothing wrong with them

Answer (score 0):

i've added the link and script tags recommended from bootstrap website to the index.html file, it somehow worked. but i don't know if it is a good practice to that.